# Checkboxgroup height too small - Checkboxes not visible

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

The size of my checkboxgroup is not enough to show all checkboxes.

Here is a fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1169

The checkboxes below "Show these detail columns" are not completely visible.
I would like to change that, but I don't find my error.
If I drag the window to increase its size, the checkboxes are shown, but since my window will contain more and more and more options, they have to be shown while the scrollbar is visible.

Comment: Remove the box layout, it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `vbox` layout for your `fieldset` and `hbox` layout for your checkboxgroup as this components by default render its items vertically and horizontally, respectively.

[Updated fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/116d)

Simply remove this properties and all will work just fine:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Columns',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Show these detail columns',
        labelAlign:'top',
        items:[{
            name:'ShowDetail',
            boxLabel: 'Date',
            inputValue:'time'
        },{
            name:'ShowDetail',
            boxLabel: 'Subject',
            inputValue:'title'
        },{
            name:'ShowDetail',
            boxLabel: 'Author',
            inputValue:'owner'
        },{
            name:'ShowDetail',
            boxLabel: 'First three words',
            inputValue:'content'
        },{
            name:'ShowDetail',
            boxLabel: 'Parent',
            inputValue:'category'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Snecha , but I think on changing this margin it will work. I verified it by making changes in the jsfiddle

```
defaults:{
        margin:'0 0 10 10'  
    },
```

to

```
defaults:{
        margin:'0 0 15 10'
},
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark the other answer as correct. I tested your change and it works, too, hence the upvote; but I guess using less code is preferable over using more code.

Comment: my answer does not even have any code change, I just changed the margin value, which you added. Thanks :)